# Mention general references in FAQ

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-faq, general-reference

In https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/5069/54 (which is mentioned in [Policy for questions that are entirely answerable with a dictionary](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/466/54)) someone's asked what the word "scholarly" means. Please don't look at this question and say "How lazy they are to ask a question like that?" Instead, think "That person isn't being lazy enough - they could have looked it up instead, rather than going to the effort of writing a question!"

In order to enable this laziness, it'd be good if the FAQ linked to resources for general references.

Comment: Perhaps by linking to [the resources list](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4710/resources-for-learning-english)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've marked this request [status-completed](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed).  A link to the [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/) (as suggested by StoneyB) has been added to the FAQ, along with a sentence explaining that such questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

On the [Ask a Question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page, the yellow dialog box to the right "How to Ask" is also good, but possibly some key caution points could be added here, rather than just linking to the faq and how to ask pages.

To me, the "how to ask" page would actually be more helpful regarding this question's topic.

Also, the "asking help" link text (in the yellow dialog box) should say something like "How to write a good question." rather than "asking help" which is bad English and seems like it would take you to a site help page. Also I couldn't see the "How to Ask" page linked to from anywhere else, including the FAQ.