# Is it ok ask for translation words?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm new in ELL site and I've read [Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help). Anyway, I have a doubt, Can I ask a question like "How to translate [word in your language] in English?" or "How to translate [word in English] in [another language]?". If yes, You could  create tags like [language-translation] (Examples: [german-translation]).

Answer (score 9):

We are not a translation service... There are thousands of translation dictionaries out there that will do word-for-word translations for you. We are not going to become another one. Any question like this will likely be closed with the basic questions close reason:

> Basic questions on spelling, meaning or pronunciation are off-topic as they should be answered using a dictionary. See: [Policy for questions that are entirely answerable with a dictionary](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/policy-for-questions-that-are-entirely-answerable-with-a-dictionary)

We will, however, help with translating concepts and idioms but this requires a lot of effort on your part.

So, if you would like to find an equivalent concept or idiom in English to one you have in your native language, you can certainly include the phrase in that language but you will need to give us a rough translation of what it means literally and what the intent of that idiom is... what it's designed to convey.

Without that general translation, we are very limited in how much we can help you as we do not necessarily speak the language you do, which means that your ability to get a good answer will be reduced.

Here are some examples of these questions that have been well received:

> [English equivalent of French "quiproquo"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55506/english-equivalent-of-french-quiproquo)
>   ["Even vinegar, once you've gotten it for free, tastes sweet": Is there an English equivalent for this saying?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97363/even-vinegar-once-youve-gotten-it-for-free-tastes-sweet-is-there-an-englis)

Comment: Another example of a single word translation that was up-voted is [English equivalent of “garam” (warming) food?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/53200/9161) - sometimes there isn't a word in English, but it's still OK to ask.