# Google Define Links

Tags: support, online-resources, hyperlinks

One of the most useful ways to get to the common definition of a word is to simply search for "define X" in Google or a browser address bar. This then gives you a definition of the word as what appears to be the top result of a regular search.

To copy and past that link back to ELL involves a massive URL that I'm not sure is static.

Is there a good way to link to "Google define" results?

Comment: Related: [What sorts of dictionaries should we use on ELL?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4721/9161). *Sometimes answers contain links to Google searches instead of links to actual dictionaries. However, this is a bad idea for a number of reasons. The most important one is that Google doesn't show definitions to all users, so the people clicking your link might not see a definition. For that reason alone, we should avoid these links.*

Comment: Also, [this discussion](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7052/is-google-dictionary-a-valid-definition-reference-in-particular-in-answers/11484#11484) on [english.se] might be interesting.

Comment: @ColleenV that is interesting. It's a shame google's current dictionary doesn't seem to be freely available online, as it is often easy to understand and I'd love to cite it directly.

Comment: Google doesn't have a dictionary. It licenses content Oxford Languages, which powers [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/) and [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/). I find searching a full dictionary more fruitful, and, for some situations, definitions from learner's dictionaries can be superior because they include easy-to-read information on countability, how common a word is, lots of example sentences, etc. Compare [Oxford Learner's](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/language?q=Language) to Google's snippet.

Comment: Indeed. But sometimes, the short and simple versions that Define pops out are exactly what a questioner needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need the `q` parameter: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+language produces

[image]

(note that the space has been transformed to a `+` – otherwise Stack Exchange thinks the link ends after 'define')

For some background, see [What are the different parameters used in Google search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/116105/136642) on our sister site Web Applications Stack Exchange.