# How should I respond to reopen my 10 days-over closed 'ask question'?

Tags: support

How should I do to reopen my 'ask question'?
it has been closed since 13 days ago.
They closed my following question.
I don't know why.
until now I don't see my chance to ask.
Who can help me.
they don't allow to delete this post.
What would I do?
Thanks you all very much.

[How should I understand the verbal phrase 'deal with'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/340467/150477)

Comment: First of all, users cannot delete a question once someone has posted an answer which has been upvoted.

Comment: Secondly, do you not see any message which explains why the question was closed? You should see `Add details and clarify the problem being solved. ` *Add details* means you explain why you do not understand "deal with", if you have looked up the term, edit and show the research in the question. Tell us what and why you don't understand. Your question has the link the source but it doesn't explain your confusion about a fairly common phrasal verb

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's already answered at https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions with a fair amount of advice and several options for reopening closed questions.

Comment: The question is on topic. Users are encouraged to come to meta and discuss how their posts can be reopened or undeleted.

Answer (score 5):

Before asking a question like this, consult a dictionary. When I looked up ["deal with" in the dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/deal-with), I found that one of the definitions matched the usage exactly. However, I'm a native speaker, so if you did that and weren't quite sure what the answer was, you should quote the definitions you think are relevant and explain your thoughts.

The question is still [in the reopen queue here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/144594), but probably shouldn't be reopened unless you can make an edit like that. Even if you can't, you shouldn't try to delete your questions (especially if answered) because that will only cause them to count even more towards a question ban. You should just focus on the questions that you can improve.

Answer (score 3):

Most of your questions on this site are the same format: asking what a word or phrase means in a context, which is fine, but you don't tell us what work you have already done to answer the question yourself with online dictionaries, and if you have done that research, you don't tell us why you're still unsure what it means.

All of your questions like that could be closed for one or both of these reasons:

- Basic questions on **spelling, meaning or pronunciation** are off-topic
  as they should be answered using a dictionary. See: [Policy for
  questions that are entirely answerable with a dictionary](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/policy-for-questions-that-are-entirely-answerable-with-a-dictionary)
- This question should include more details than have been provided here.
  Please edit to **add the research** you have done in your efforts to
  answer the question, or provide more context.

So I recommend following the advice in Laurel's answer to this question, and also to edit your old questions --especially ones that have some close votes-- to add the research you have done, what you found, and why you're still unsure.